# Remove border in select option when active

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, styles

Have you already noticed that Google have recently implemented a border in select option when active for Chrome? Any ideas how to disable this functionality? Firefox doen't have this border.

Google chrome Version 83.0.4103.61 (64-bit)

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        select option:focus {
            border:0px;
            outline:0px;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            outline: none !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <select>
        <option>Test11</option>
        <option>Test22</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

[jsfiddle.net/fq3korhg/](https://jsfiddle.net/fq3korhg/)

Comment: This is a new usability redesign across multiple browsers and platforms. While I appreciate the goal, the end result on select lists is ugly. Setting `outline: none` like the two answers below has no effect on this. https://blog.chromium.org/2020/03/updates-to-form-controls-and-focus.html

Comment: Also: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/48974735?hl=en

Comment: You can disable in Chrome by going to chrome://flags/#form-controls-refresh and disabling "Web Platform Controls updated UI".  But that's obviously just for you and your browser, and won't help you correctly style your site. In fact, it hides the ugly that all other users will still see.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this:

```
select:focus {
    outline:none;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for the latest version of Google Chrome

Answer (score -1):

Need to set property for select:

```
select:focus {
  outline: none; 
}
```